# Show that $ \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{49} n(52-n)(51-n)(50-n)}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} = 10.6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, expected-value, combinatorial-proofs

I have a hard time showing that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{49} n(52-n)(51-n)(50-n)}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} 
&= \frac{1}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} \left[ (1 \cdot 51 \cdot50\cdot 49) +(2 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48) + \ldots + (49 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) \right]\\
&=10.6
\end{align*}
I am not sure how to deal with/simplify the sum of the running products $(52-n)(51-n)(50-n)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: k=1 to 49? I think it should be **n** =1 to 49.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It is corrected.

Comment: Are you saying value is *exactly* $10.6,$ as in the rational number $53/5$? Or is $10.6$ an approximation?

Comment: I believe the value should be exactly 10.6.

Comment: @GavinKe With $\,n \mapsto 51-n\,$ the sum is $\,\sum_{n=2}^{50} (-n^4 + 51 n^3 + n^2 - 51 n)\,$ which is not so difficult to calculate even without clever shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

By reversing the order of summation $n \mapsto 52-n$, the desired identity is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n=3}^{51} \frac{(52-n)n(n-1)(n-2)}{13 \cdot 51\cdot 50 \cdot 49}=\frac{53}{5}.$$
Now multiply both sides by $52 \cdot 51\cdot 50 \cdot 49/4!$ to obtain
$$\sum_{n=3}^{51} \frac{(52-n)n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}=\frac{53 \cdot 52 \cdot 51\cdot 50 \cdot 49}{5!},$$
which we can rewrite as
$$\sum_{n=3}^{51} \binom{n}{3}\binom{52-n}{1}=\binom{53}{5}.$$
This last identity can be proved combinatorially by counting $5$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,53\}$ in two different ways.  The RHS is clear.  For the LHS, condition on the fourth smallest value $n+1$.  Then you must choose $3$ elements from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $1$ element from $\{n+2,\dots,53\}$.

---

Alternatively, skip the first step of reversing the order of summation.
Instead rewrite as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{49} \binom{n}{1}\binom{52-n}{3}=\binom{53}{5},$$
which you can prove combinatorially by conditioning on the fourth largest (equivalently, second smallest) element $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{49} n(52-n)(51-n)(50-n)}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} 
&= \frac{1}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{49}(132600n-7802n ^2+153n^3-n^4) \right]\\
\end{align*}$

As,

$\begin{align*}
{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{ n(n+1)}{2} }\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\frac{ n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} }\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3=\frac{ n^2(n+1)^2}{4} }\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^4=\frac{ n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30} }\end{align*}$

Therefore,

$\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{49}(132600n-7802n ^2+153n^3-n^4) \right]=\frac{1}{13 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49} \left[ 17218110 \right]=10.6\\
\end{align*}$